# He publicado una aplicación de Windows Forms .NET 5 (C#), pero me da error porque dice que no tengo permisos para la carpeta "ProgramFiles"

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, permisos, .net-5

Tengo una aplicación que utiliza .NET 5 (C#). En ella, se maneja una base de datos, un documento XML y se crea un archivo que va registrando los errores. Ahora bien, he creado un instalador que me la instala en el directorio de "Archivos de programas". Sin embargo, cuando quiero realizar escritura sobre esos archivos (base de datos, documento XML o archivo que registra errores) me lanza una excepción que me dice que no tiene acceso al directorio. Me imagino que tendría que forzar constantemente a que mi aplicación tuviera permisos de administrador, ¿pero hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo para que solo tenga acceso a su carpeta creada en "Archivos de programas" y sus respectivos archivos?
Lo único que he encontrado es darle permisos de administrador incluyendo esta línea:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Pero me gustaría otra alternativa en la que no hiciera falta hacerlo. Otros programas instalados, no piden permisos de administrador y están también en esa carpeta y siguen siendo funcionales. ¿Hay otra alternativa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras investigar, citando de las fuentes de este enlace de SO en inglés, he visto que no es muy buena práctica incluir los archivos de los datos de la aplicación en la carpeta de "Archivos de Programa". Por tanto, guardo mejor los datos de mi aplicación en C:\ProgramData[MiApp], utilizando: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`

```
var ruta = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)),
                            "MiApp");
// Esto devuelve la ruta C:\ProgramData\MiApp
```

**Fuente:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849929/file-access-denied-while-accessing-from-program-files